# How do I save AudioRecording to app folder?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, avaudiorecorder

I am working on a app with recording function and followed a tutorial on this. I would like to edit the function where the AudioRecorder saves the file so that the file goes in the same folder it would if I dragged an audiofile directly in to xcode.
I am having trouble fetching a singe recording from the directory the Audiorecorder is saving to atm and found another tutorial that shows how to find recordings based on name from the app folder.
This is the recordings func today:

```
func startRecording() {
        let recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try recordingSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
            try recordingSession.setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to set up recording session")
        }
        
        let documentPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        print("AUDIORECORDER document path: \(documentPath)")
        let audioFilename = documentPath.appendingPathComponent("\(Date().toString(dateFormat: "dd-MM-YY_'at'_HH:mm:ss")).m4a")
        print("AUDIORECORDER audioFilename: \(audioFilename)")
        let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
        ]
        
        do {
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
            audioRecorder.record()
            
            recording = true
        } catch {
            print("Could not start recording")
        }
        
        
    }
```

Any idea on how to do this? The tutorial only shows how to fetch all recordings to a list and I am trying to fetch a single recording. This is the fetch function if this helpes:

```
func fetchRecordings() {
            recordings.removeAll()
            
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
            let directoryContents = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
            for audio in directoryContents {
                
                let recording = Recording(fileURL: audio, createdAt: getCreationDate(for: audio))
                          recordings.append(recording)
            }
    
                
                objectWillChange.send(self)
        }
```

It does not really matter where it saves but I need to be able to save the name to a string (So that I can fetch the right audio to the right object) and then find the audio based on that string.
Thank you.

Comment: Use a database or a file to store the file names. The db or file object can be accessed through a shared object throughput the all app.

Comment: I do have Core database, and the file name is supposed to be stored as a String in my Entity but I can't get the filename to work when I want to play the audio.

Comment: Do you save absolute file path or relative file path ? The directories of the application may change between two launch.

Comment: I had an relative and that was why I got an error. The path changed every time I launched. I fixed it by searching on the last 14 letters when I wanted to search for the file, they are always the same. :-)

Comment: So you need compute the full pathname : documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(audio)